# Why this query explain not contains "using where"

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am testing the queries for my website (developing) but I found there is something strange I can't understand, look at the Red Star line - why this query explain not contains "using where"

Could anyone can explain about that? Thank you very much

mysqldump sample download (zip 46.9 MB): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ve2F7eRJk4eUJteXppRVYzMk0

MariaDB 10.1.9 - InnoDB engine

Comment: At first glance I'd say *log_timesamp* does have an index (that can be used in the query), while *log_type* doesn't.

Comment: log_type is not that important, I added it to see the extra information.

Comment: Actually I am wondering the opposite thing: why there is "using where" in your 2nd to last query at all, while I think your last execution plan is correct. ICP should not need to be "using where" there. What is your mysql version?

Comment: Just tested it: ICP in 5.7 works as expected, 5.6 shows your behaviour when you use `order by` and have a gap in your composite index. You can include the missing index-column into your 2nd to last query, e.g. `and not log_action is null` (if that does not exclude any row -  the point is to just include the column in the query to not skip a column of the index) to get rid of the `using where` too. It probably doesn't qualify as a bug, it is just less optimal behaviour - but that is why we get new mysql versions with improved optimizers.

Comment: "using where" in 2nd query because "log_type" field is not in the Multiple column index, so the query only uses log_user (1st column in the multiple column index) index, and then "using where" to filter the result. I wonder the Red Star query should be too, but it doesn't, I'm confused.  (Update my question to add sample file and mysql version information)

Comment: I meant the 2nd to last query (the one before the star). Both the marked and the one before that should not be "using where", because ICP can work without it (as it does in the last query). (And it should work correctly in 5.7). For some reason, `order by` in combination with the gap in the multi column index makes 5.6 (and thus probably mariadb 10.1) read the row, which is a little non-optimal. If you close the gap in the query before the star (e.g. add `and not log_action is null`), similar to your 4th query (which has no gap), ICP will work without "using where" again.